# What Java class can I extend to?

Tags: java

What Java class can I extend to so that I gain inheritance to treeTableView? How do I extend a class that is already extended?

I'm currently extending it using treeTableView.

The demo file shows this:

```
final TreeItem<User> root = new RecursiveTreeItem<User>(users, RecursiveTreeObject::getChildren);
```

This is what I tried working out, but it's not working:

```
final TreeItem<Patient> root = new Patient(patients, Patient::getChildren);
```

What do I do?

Comment: can you use interfaces?

Comment: No, the RecursiveTreeItem is a class and so is the Person class. The structure is: Person => Patient. I can't have both.

Comment: Please provide more details about your code, what errors you get and have a look at http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I extended the Person superclass to RecursiveTreeObject. Through inheritance it worked.

Comment: so the question is "how do I extend a class" and answer is "I extended the class". how is this useful?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I made the question more specific